# Moss 2007 Re-Ghost Content Types

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, content-type, moss

Say for example I have Content Type XXX.  For some reason it has become unghosted on List A.  We have changed the content type in our feature and re-deployed but obviously the content type on List A has not been updated.  Is it possible to reghost this content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ReGhost](http://www.reghost.net/)? I'm not sure it helps you but its worth a shot. Here's a quote from them

> [ReGhost] will locate all of your content
>   databases on the network, and examine
>   them for unghostedindependent pages -
>   it then allows you to select which
>   content you wish to revert.  Once
>   selected, it will essentially reset
>   the content, aka “reghost” the content
>   - making it possible for your migration to complete successfully.

Comment: Will existing content be preserved?

Comment: It should. Of course like always, try it out in a test environment before you do it in production.